# Azure Automatic Data Classification

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

In Azure, they have automated suggestions for data classification (for data being hosted in SQL Server hosted in Azure that is) and the ability to auto approve these suggestions by going through the UI and clicking. Is it possible to automate that as well? I know I could go through the UI and build labels and do a whole lot of boring monotonous clicking and achieve these results, but that isnt very efficient.

Any insights or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use [T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/data-discovery-and-classification-overview#use-t-sql) to manage classifications.
First we need to use sql query to generate the `ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION`  script.
According to its grammar, use sql query to splice out the desired script

```
    ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO
    <object_name> [, ...n ]
    WITH ( <sensitivity_option> [, ...n ] )

<object_name> ::=
{
    [schema_name.]table_name.column_name
}

<sensitivity_option> ::=  
{
    LABEL = string |
    LABEL_ID = guidOrString |
    INFORMATION_TYPE = string |
    INFORMATION_TYPE_ID = guidOrString |
    RANK = NONE | LOW | MEDIUM | HIGH | CRITICAL
}
```

For example, below is the TSQL script I created the foreign key before:

```sql
select
   concat(concat('alter table ',c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA),concat('.',fk.TABLE_NAME)),
   concat(' add constraint  ', c.CONSTRAINT_NAME),  --cu.COLUMN_NAME
   concat(' foreign key( ',cu.COLUMN_NAME),
   concat(concat(') references ',c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA),concat('.',pk.TABLE_NAME)),
   concat(concat('(',pt.COLUMN_NAME),');')
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS c
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS fk
    on c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk
    on c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
    on c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join  (
            select
                i1.TABLE_NAME,
                i2.COLUMN_NAME
            from
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
            inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                on i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            where
                i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    on pt.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
```

I think it’s more difficult to stitch `ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION` T-SQL script.

Comment: Oh I can totally do this in TSQL, which I was already aware of. I was just hoping there was a way to automatically accept Microsoft's suggestions, which is what I was asked to do. Thank you very much though.